# InvalidUrlError: Invalid bucket name in URL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

gsutil mb -p [PROJECT_ID] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]PROJECT_ID is the Project ID in the lab details panel on the left of this lab:

BUCKET_NAME is the name you give to the bucket. You can use the Project ID as the bucket name to ensure a globally unique name:

whenever I use correct projectid i'm getting the same error multiple times
InvalidUrlError: Invalid bucket name in URL

wanted to create a cloud storage bucket for my cloud function